# Get Maven Dependency Version in Jenkins Build

Tags: maven, jenkins, dependencies, pom.xml

I have a Jenkins Job where I need the version of a dependency (from pom.xml) to download it from Nexus.

I tried with `call mvn help:evaluate ...` and got the correct version.
But I can´t assign it to a variable or save it to file.

Is there a way to do that or a plugin that evaluates this directly?

Comment: Downloading a dependency for a Maven build from SVN ? Do you use a repository manager ? If not start to use one...

Comment: Indeed it seems strange that you use modern tools like Jenkins and Maven on the one hand, but store artifacts in SVN...

Comment: Sorry, i mean Nexus not SVN. I changed it.